# Attribute Error: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to create a 30 minute time bucket and i'm getting a the following attribute error:

> 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

The column being ingested is called timestamp and holds the schema type timestamp. e.g.

> 2019-02-01T15:53:44Z

I can't work out why i'm getting the error given the below code should be able to ingest the timestamp.

```
    def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta

df = df.withColumn("bucket_timestamp", ceil_dt(df.timestamp, timedelta(minutes=30)))
return df
```

Comment: Hi, which version of pyspark are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of a user defined function (UDF):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# example DF
date = datetime.strptime('2019-02-01T15:53:44', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
df = sc.parallelize([Row(timestamp=date)]).toDF()

# define UDF based on OP's function
ceil_dt = (f.udf(lambda dt, delta:  dt + (datetime.min - dt) % timedelta(minutes=delta),
                TimestampType()))

# now apply to timestamp columns
df = df.withColumn("bucket_timestamp", ceil_dt(df.timestamp, f.lit(30)))
```

Comment: hi, could you explain why a udf is required? Is there any reason this can't be done without one?